# Variable selection : combining AIC and Cross validation

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, feature-selection, p-value

I'm currently working on a dataset and I'm using the AIC criterion with the function step in R to achieve variable selection. 
Doing so, my model has reduced from 48 variables to this 24 variables one :

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2576.8  -190.4   -93.8    33.4 15548.2 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  270.472     16.482  16.410  < 2e-16 ***
order        382.376     33.294  11.485  < 2e-16 ***
report       232.535     25.863   8.991  < 2e-16 ***
`000`        152.409     27.783   5.486 4.36e-08 ***
font          59.870      8.333   7.185 7.94e-13 ***
re           -33.898      8.701  -3.896 9.95e-05 ***
receive      248.213     51.176   4.850 1.28e-06 ***
people       113.395     29.255   3.876 0.000108 ***
you          -25.046      5.503  -4.551 5.48e-06 ***
george       -17.225      5.100  -3.377 0.000738 ***
money         66.370     21.565   3.078 0.002100 ** 
addresses    131.646     40.453   3.254 0.001146 ** 
remove       -77.934     23.188  -3.361 0.000784 ***
`650`        -34.678     19.511  -1.777 0.075575 .  
meeting      -34.344     11.319  -3.034 0.002427 ** 
make          77.576     30.773   2.521 0.011743 *  
project      -30.727     13.822  -2.223 0.026266 *  
edu          -20.688      9.757  -2.120 0.034028 *  
pm           -36.348     20.704  -1.756 0.079223 .  
`1999`        51.903     23.057   2.251 0.024430 *  
original     -70.763     41.520  -1.704 0.088396 .  
labs         -39.932     23.732  -1.683 0.092524 .  
mail          23.066     13.974   1.651 0.098894 .  
your         -12.496      8.503  -1.470 0.141754    
free         -16.432     11.457  -1.434 0.151583    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 575.9 on 4185 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1385,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1336 
F-statistic: 28.04 on 24 and 4185 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now, the variables "free" and "your" don't seem to be significant.
To decide whether to keep them in my model or not, I have compared the models with/without "your" and with/without "free" repeating 20 times a 10-fold-cross validation.
Code :

```
---------testing if "your" is useful to the model----------------- 
me=0
mf=0
for (i in c(1:20)) {
  e<-cv.lm(model, fit3, m=10,printit=FALSE,seed=i) #fit3 is the model without "your"
  f<-cv.lm(model, fit, m=10,printit=FALSE,seed=i) #fit is the unrestricted model
  me=me+attr(e,"ms")
  mf=mf+attr(f,"ms")
}
me=me/20 #result : 334718
mf=mf/20 #result : 334659 ==> we keep "your"

---------testing if "free" is useful to the model----------------- 

me=0
mf=0
for (i in c(1:20)) {
  e<-cv.lm(model, fit2, m=10,printit=FALSE,seed=i) #fit2 is the model without "free"
  f<-cv.lm(model, fit, m=10,printit=FALSE,seed=i) #fit is the unrestricted model
  me=me+attr(e,"ms")
  mf=mf+attr(f,"ms")
}
me=me/20 #result : 334726
mf=mf/20 #result : 334659 ==> we keep "free"
```

Now my questions are the following : 
-Is that a good way to proceed ? (Meaning : should I use CV to determine whether to keep those variables in my model or not ?)
-Or should I perform some kind of hypothesis test to assess the relevance of those two variables ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If your writing for a scientific journal then significance testing is important but if your trying to build a good model for predicting outcomes it is less so. In my opinion cross validation trumps hypothesis testing. If the two variables improve the  predictability of your model when cross validated you should include them.

Comment: Think this belongs on stats.stackoverflow.com as you are not asking how to do this in R, but are asking a statistics question.